# Redirect %20%E2%80%8E

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this customer that send an email with `http://url/%20%E2%80%8E` and everyone is getting a 404 not found. So he asked me for a redirection and I though sure easy. But it looks like is not working... please help!!

I tried this:

```
 redirect 301 /\%20\%E2\%80\%8E http://url/promo-content/
 and
 redirect 301 /%20%E2%80%8E http://url/promo-content/
```

and is not working..

I also tried this

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\%20\%E2\%80\%8E$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://url/promo-content/%1/ [R,L]
```

But still not working... any sugestion???

Answer (score 0):

The URI gets decoded first before mod_rewrite rules are applied. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\ â€Ž /promo-content/ [L,R=301]
```