# Would Like to redirect http://www.myweb.com/%E2%80%A6/myfile.htm

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried adjusting the examples given in other post, but cannot get them to work.

I am trying to get:

```
      http://www.myweb.com/%E2%80%A6/myfile.htm
```

to redirect to:

```
      http://www.myweb.com/mydirectory/myfile.htm
```

I tried 301 which obviously will not work, as the /%E2%80%A6 is an ellipse used by some websites to shorten the url.
I also tried RewriteRule, which I am not that good at. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hex code directly in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\xE2\x80\xA6/(myfile\.htm)$ mydirectory/$1 [L,NE,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to redirect http://www.bentonswcd.org/resources/rural-living/%20%E2%80%8E to http://www.bentonswcd.org/resources/rural-living/. I tried the suggestion here and in these other posts and none worked: 
[Trying to Redirect 301 %E2%80%A6 in htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183230/trying-to-redirect-301-e280a6-in-htaccess-file)
[Redirect %20%E2%80%8E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739473/redirect-20e2808e)
[How to redirect %E2%80%8E and other weird links to right place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024846/how-to-redirect-e2808e-and-other-weird-links-to-right-place)

Then a friend of mine suggested this fix, and it worked great. Hope it can work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\%20%E2%80%8E(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```